# Change the font used in the Breeze SDDM theme

Tags: fonts, sddm

The default Breeze theme for SDDM on KDE uses default fonts from somewhere I don't know of. In earlier versions of KDE/SDDM, there used to be specific files in the SDDM themes where a font could be set (using something like `font.family` in `PlasmaComponents.Label`). However, in newer versions (Plasma/sddm-breeze 5.10.1-1, sddm 0.14.0-10 on Fedora 26) everything seems to have been rearranged and I can't find any file(s) where the font can clearly/obviously be set.

I would like to change the font for preferably *all* UI elements. I found [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/56l8rn/is_there_any_way_of_changing_the_sddm_default_font/) but couldn't glean much useful information from it. One option in particular, got by following a link in that post, is to just [change the system's default (fallback) fonts](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/718#issuecomment-297484548), and that is something I *definitely* don't want to do (I need the default fonts as they are for other reasons). I also tried the option mentioned in the original post, by the author of an SDDM theme, of [setting the font in the `theme.conf` file](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/56l8rn/is_there_any_way_of_changing_the_sddm_default_font/db0wc5i/), but to no avail. (To be fair, the author does mention that this technique won't work with other themes. :( )

Is there really a way to change the SDDM font, particularly for the Breeze theme?

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the theme to allow this customisation, look at [Breeze2](https://github.com/avivace/breeze2-sddm-theme).

Comment: **Reviewers: This post seems to be a fix of the problem from the software author. Check the github link!** Sorry for mistakenly flagging it as NAA. :-(